# Overriding a method gives a conflict or doesn't find its parent equivalent

Tags: swift

When I try to override the `ttTabBar` function from `TTTabBar` this way:

```
override func ttTabBar(tabBar: TabBar, shouldChangeTab tabBarItem: TabBarItem) -> Bool {

    for var i = 0; i < tabBar.tabBarItems.count; i++ {
        tabBar.tabBarItems[i].unselectItem()
    }

    tabBarItem.selectItem()
    return true
}
```

I get this:

> Method does not override any method from its superclass

Which is wrong from my knowledge:

```
public class TTTabBar: UIViewController {
    internal func ttTabBar(tabBar: TTTabBar, shouldChangeTab tabBarItem: TTTabBarItem) -> Bool {
        if tabBarItem.isButton {
            self.ttTabBar(tabBar, buttonHasBeenClicked: tabBarItem)
            return false
        }

        return true
    }

    internal func ttTabBar(tabBar: TTTabBar, tabWillDisappear tabBarItem: TTTabBarItem) {

    }

    internal func ttTabBar(tabBar: TTTabBar, tabDidDisappear tabBarItem: TTTabBarItem) {

    }

    internal func ttTabBar(tabBar: TTTabBar, tabWillAppear tabBarItem: TTTabBarItem) {

    }

    internal func ttTabBar(tabBar: TTTabBar, tabDidAppear tabBarItem: TTTabBarItem) {

    }

    internal func ttTabBar(tabBar: TTTabBar, buttonHasBeenClicked tabBarItem: TTTabBarItem) {

    }
}
```

Still, I remove the `override` keyword but then I get this, which by the way, shows me he knows about what I am trying to override:

> Method 'ttTabBar(*:shouldChangeTab:)' with Objective-C selector
>   'ttTabBar:shouldChangeTab:' conflicts with method
>   'ttTabBar(*:shouldChangeTab:)' from superclass 'TTTabBar' with the
>   same Objective-C selector

I found that to avoid the latter, I could add the `@nonobjc` property but I don't feel like it's a good way to go. Moreover since I am not sure what is going on here. Plus, I just discovered it actually doesn't behave as I expected. `TTTabBar` calls `ttTabBar` internally but it doesn't call my version of it, which is what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method signatures have to be identical to the method being overridden. See this example:

```
class TestX {
    func afunc(name: String) {

    }
}

class TestY : TestX {
    override func afunc(name: Bool) {
        // complains about not needing override.
    }
}

class TestZ : TestX {
    override func afunc(name: String) {
        // compiles
    }
}
```

In your code, the method signatures are slightly different.

Type TTTabBarItem and TabBarItem are not the same.

Comment: OK. Thanks. I guess I have to look for something different to get it to work the way I want :)